# Oracle unique constraint violation referencing a constraint that doesn't seem to exist

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, unique-constraint

I'm receiving an error that I can't make sense of. The error is pretty straightforward:

```
ORA-00001: unique constraint (*schema*.*xyz_constraint*) violated
```

However, what's causing my confusion is the fact that no such constraint seems to exist. It's certainly not defined on the table; the DB in question has almost no referential integrity defined, and the particular table into which I'm inserting data has no key defined.

For what it's worth, I can't find the constraint anywhere in the database:

```
    select *
    from all_constraints 
    where constraint_name like '%xyz_constraint%'
```

Is there anything I'm overlooking? Thanks.

Comment: When an attempt is made such that a unique **index** would have a duplicate, Oracle will report as a unique **constraint** violation. So I would suggest looking for unique indexes in addition to constraints.

Comment: You can find your indexes in the table `all_indexes`. You can do: `select index_name, table_name, uniqueness from all_indexes where upper(index_name) = upper('xyz_constraint');` to find which table has this index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens when the constraint belongs to another user and you don't have permissions to it.

Try looking it once again for now from SYS perspective

Comment: I'll have to engage one of the DBAs. Naturally, I don't have SYS access to the schema. It'll be interesting to see what's up, since this has been in prod for two+ years without a constraint issue. Today I got 600 errors. Thanks for the feedback; I'll let you know what I find.

Comment: @Ickster: I don't remember the causes, but I had exactly the same behaviour and it was what I said ;-) Anyway, good luck in your research and looking forward for details what it actually was in your case

Comment: Just query `DBA_CONSTRAINTS` instead. If you have access to this view, then if the constraint exists, it'll be there. `SYS` is not necessarily required - `SYSTEM` would also have access to it.

Comment: @Jeffrey Kemp - thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I don't have access to that view either. Our DBAs like to make sure no one can figure anything out without asking them for help. And then they complain about being asked for help ;-)

Comment: Sheesh. It's been years, but I should mention that it was in fact a permissions issue as @zerkms suggested. Our DBA was able to resolve it.

Answer (score 8):

I had the exact same error and it was not a permissions issue. Rather, the entity turned out to be an `INDEX` not a `CONSTRAINT` and I found it with:

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_INDEXES WHERE INDEX_NAME LIKE '%XYZ_UK1'
```

...because it did not exist in `ALL_CONSTRAINTS` or `DBA_CONSTRAINTS`. Confusing how the error message is the same. I'm running Oracle 11g.

Comment: Thanks, I had exactly the same issue and it was driving me crazy, it never occured to me to check the indexes instead of the constraints

Answer (score 1):

Schema object names are almost always stored in upper-case. Try

```
select *
from all_constraints 
where constraint_name like '%XYZ_CONSTRAINT%'
```

ORA-00001 usually happens for duplicate primary keys. Are you sure you don't have one on the table?

Comment: The actual query I ran contained the constraint name exactly as it was returned in the error I received. I'm positive there's no key defined on the table. The only constraints are NOT NULL declarations on several fields.